# implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0' Error When I Update implementation 'com.android.support.play-services-ads:17.0.0'

Tags: android

implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0'  Error When I Update implementation 'com.android.support.play-services-ads:17.0.0'

Comment: "*Help me*" is not a question. Please take your time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read the link suggested by @Johan. This is not how you ask questions in SO.

Answer (score 0):

> instead of 
>   implementation 'com.android.support.play-services-ads:17.0.0' use

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

> and instead of  implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' use

```
implementation 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-28.0.0'
```

> and Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to
>    the `google()` repo or to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`.

for more details refer to [setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and [support library packages page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)